# do mDNS and LLMNR queries use the same format as tcp DNS?

Tags: dns, multicast

mDNS clients send queries to 224.0.0.251:5353

LLMNR clients send queries to 224.0.0.252:5355

Is their packets format the same as good old fashioned tcp dns ?

Let suppose I want to resolve the hostname *test.local* sending the usual DNS "standard query, one question".
Does the DNS packet  fit also mDNS and LLMNR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia on "Multicast DNS":

> It is a zero-configuration service, using essentially the same
>   programming interfaces, packet formats and operating semantics as the
>   unicast Domain Name System (DNS).

Wikipedia on "Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution":

> The Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) is a protocol based
>   on the Domain Name System (DNS) packet format that allows both IPv4
>   and IPv6 hosts to perform name resolution for hosts on the same local
>   link.

So yes, packet formats are all the same.